# Intersection of two subspaces and their linearly dependence

Tags: linear-algebra

$U$ and $W$ are subspaces of $V$ and $U \cap W =  \left\{ 0 \right\} $.
$\left\{ (U_1, U_2, ... , U_r) \right\}$ is a basis for $U$ and $\left\{ (W_1, W_2, ... , W_s) \right\}$ is a basis for $W$. Show that $\left\{ (U_1, U_2, ... , U_r, W_1, W_2, ... , W_s) \right\}$ are L.I. Will it be L.I if $U \cap W \neq  \left\{ 0 \right\} $?

My answer:
$$
\alpha_1 U_1+ \alpha_2 U_2+ ... + \alpha_r U_r = \beta_1 W_1+ \beta_2 W_2+ ... +\beta_s W_s\\
\alpha_1 U_1+ \alpha_2 U_2+ ... + \alpha_r U_r - \beta_1 W_1 - \beta_2 W_2 - ...  -\beta_s W_s = 0
$$Since their intersection is $\left\{ 0 \right\}$ we get:
$$
\alpha_1,\alpha_2 ... \alpha_r, \beta_1, \beta_2 ... \beta_s = 0
$$Therefore:
$$
\left\{(U_1, U_2, ... , U_r, W_1, W_2, ... , W_s) \right\} \text{are L.I}
$$But if we assume that $U \cap W \neq  \left\{ 0 \right\} $ we get:
$$
\alpha_1 U_1+ \alpha_2 U_2+ ... + \alpha_r U_r = \beta_1 W_1+ \beta_2 W_2+ ... +\beta_s W_s\\
$$Concluding that it will exist some scalar $\alpha_n $ and $ \beta_m$ not null, thus:
$$
\left\{(U_1, U_2, ... , U_r, W_1, W_2, ... , W_s) \right\} \text{are not L.I}
$$

Is everything correct?!

Thanks

Comment: You seem to have commas where plus signs should be in some of your equations.

Comment: Yeah! Copy and paste result... haha Illl edit it